# Вывод html текста из модели в DJANGO

Tags: python, django

Есть модель в django

```
#  Слайдер на главной на темном фоне
class MainDarkSlider(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Заголовок c тегами html', max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField('Описание',  blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Слайдер на главной'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Слайдеры на главной'
```

В поле title в админке я хочу ввести текст с html тегами, но django html экранирует, в итоге мне на странице сайта такой текст

[image: Результат работы данной модели.]

Вместо такого как в html верстке

[image: Сверстанный макет в html]
Как мне поправить модель?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй `{{ obj.description|safe }}` при выводе в шаблоне
Подробней о фильтрах можно посмотреть https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe